# React - TypeError: jokes.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api-design

I am relatively new to React and I am trying to build a simple app that queries a Chuck Norris API and returns a random joke. When I run my code in the browser I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: jokes.map is not a function
```

My theory is 'map' expects an array - which my json data object is not - however I am not positive and unsure as to what / how to tweak my code if that even is the case.

Here is my code:

This is App.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Norris from './components/norris';


class App extends Component {
 render() {
    return (
        <Norris jokes={this.state.jokes} />
    )
 }

 state = {
    jokes: []
 };

 componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState({ jokes: data})
        })
        .catch(console.log)
}

}

export default App;
```

Here is norris.js:

```
import React from 'react'

const Norris = ({jokes}) => {
 return (
    <div>
        <center><h1>Norris Jokes</h1></center>
        {jokes.map((joke) => (
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{joke.value}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
 )
};

export default Norris
```

Comment: try `jokes && jokes.map(joke=>(YOUR_REMAINING_CODE))` .This only works only if your `jokes` is an array.

Comment: Check what data is before you set it to state. It may not be an array.

Comment: jokes is populated async so on initial render it will be undefined. when the response returns it will have data. This can be fixed by checking jokes is not undefined first.

Comment: @JacobSmit It's initial value is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response of https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random is not an array

If you want jokes as an array you can change your code like the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState({ jokes: [data]})
        })
        .catch(console.log)
}
```

Comment: go idea , and he must add checking for value before maping , jokes && jocks.map

Answer (score 0):

I checked you API end point `https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random` it does not return any array at all, neither is there any `data` variable within the object that it returns.

The output is an object with some properties:

```js
fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
           console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(console.log)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, the endpoint doesn't provide an array, but a single joke, wrapped with a JSON like this:

```
{
categories: [ ],
created_at: "2020-01-05 13:42:20.841843",
icon_url: "https://assets.chucknorris.host/img/avatar/chuck-norris.png",
id: "cFdQaTXXRJS_tIKa_xuqOg",
updated_at: "2020-01-05 13:42:20.841843",
url: "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/cFdQaTXXRJS_tIKa_xuqOg",
value: "Chuck Norris can ride a BMX bike while wearing bigass MC Hammer parachute pants."
}
```

(Kinda lame, this one).
So instead of `jokes.map(//...`, first, rename the prop to `joke`, and second, leave just

```
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{joke.value}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The API you've called is just for **ONE** random joke, not a list of jokes (Array of Objects).

[You can check this code sandbox with a working code.](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-river-nr1mi?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

[Or here if you want a list with multiple jokes.](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-frog-2qlhg?file=/src/App.js)

Cheers!

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";    
import Norris from "./Norris";
    
    export default function App() {
      const [state, setState] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          fetch("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random")
            .then((result) => result.json())
            .then((data) => setState((s) => [...s, data.value]))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div style={{ fontFamily: "sans-serif" }}>
          <Norris jokes={state} />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

**Norris.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default function Norris({ jokes }) {

      return (
        <>
          <h1>Norris Jokes</h1>
          <ul>
            {jokes.map((joke, index) => (
              <li key={index}>{joke}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </>
      );
    }
```